Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
I have the following code
 if let id = items[indexPath.row]["id"] {
     if let idx = savedGoals.index(of: id) {
        savedGoals.remove(at: idx)
     }
 }

I get the error Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
on line if let idx = savedGoals.index(of: id) {
savedGoals is declared as
var savedGoals = []

does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

As the documentation of index(of:) clearly states, the method is only available for Arrays whose Elements are Equatable. Your savedGoals array is inferred to have type Any, which doesn't conform to Equatable. You need to use a more specific type than Any in your type declaration.

With no offense intended, but items looks suspiciously like an array of dictionaries (such as may have been created from JSONSerialization or the like). A strongly-typed language like Swift really excels when you use custom types (and JSONDecoder) rather than just collections of arrays and dictionaries with Any…

You will want to be more explicit in your use of types, to minimize the use of Any:

You say that savedGoals has been declared as:
var savedGoals = []

I am surprised that worked at all, as usually that would result in yield an error such as:

Empty collection literal requires an explicit type

Regardless, you can resolve this ambiguity by specifying a type, e.g., either:
var savedGoals: [Int] = []                         // or `[String]` or whatever

We can’t tell what type this id is from these code snippets, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Assuming that items is an array of dictionaries, you will likely need to be more specific in the type of id, too. Thus, instead of:
if let id = items[indexPath.row]["id"] {…}

Perhaps:
if let id = items[indexPath.row]["id"] as? Int {…} // or `as? String` or whatever



